# Custom login form with signin button -- POSTing registration

Tags: users

I have added a "register" button to the login form which is shown as a block on my homepage. I want the button to simply redirect to the registration page but it's POSTing to login and error'ing -- any ideas?

```
  function MYMODULE_form_user_login_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $form['actions']['register'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Sign Up'),
      '#submit' => array('_user_login_register_submit')
    );    
  }

  function _user_login_register_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    drupal_goto('user/register');
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because the login form validate handler is executed, and fails, before the function you call with the #submit attribute.

You can use #validate like a workaround probably, but there's a cleaner way to achieve what you are after.

I wouldn't create a button element at all. Make it a link to user/register instead and style it to look like a button if needed.

Comment: A link is a more elegant solution...didn't even think of that. Thanks :)